# How to recover Linux from 'repair file system' error

Tags: linux, shell, opensuse

Unfortunately my mom did something that I don't know and Linux is in command-line 
mode. What is the key for exiting from the shell and going to the desktop?

I tried

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- exit

No one worked for me. It goes to the black shell and tells me enter login and root password. When I enter it, it shows me repair file system in red color. 
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> shows me a blank black page and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> will return back to this shell.

My version is [openSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) 11.1.

Comment: try Alt + F1 ___

Comment: it did nothing for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"shows me repair file system in red color"

This is the key: the filesystem is corrupted, probably due to an unclean shutdown. It needs to be repaired. Try entering the root password, which should give you a '#' prompt. Type:

fsck -A -y

That will take a while and print out something about what it's fixing. Once that has completed, type "exit". You may need to restart the system again.

Comment: yes It is tell me fixed fixed fixed and It has questions which itself tells yes yes yes hope It will help thanks

Comment: I love you so much!!!! thanks thanks what can I do for you!!!! thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Take it it's working then :) If you could edit the subject line of your original question to something like "How to recover linux from 'repair file system' error" that would be great. Also, now you've got your files back BACK THEM UP SOMEWHERE.

Comment: :D Yes I should do it! ok I change the subject for users:)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> should return you to the GUI if it is still running. If not, try `startx`.

Comment: it showed me nothing

Answer (score 1):

The CLI (Command Line Interface) is not a "window" or program in Linux like it is in recent versions of Windows.

So you are not trying to *Exit* the CLI, you are trying to *Start* the Graphical User Interface (GUI).

First off: Have you restarted the computer? And what version or Distro are you using?

**Update 1:**

Instructions for starting KDE from CLI in opensuse are to run the command:

```
startx
```

or

```
startkde
```

**Update 2:**

From http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11550.html

> The first thing to do is to make sure that KDE will start up from the command line. On SUSE, KDE is installed into the /opt/kde3 folder and all the commands can be found in the bin sub folder. This directory will probably not be in your path as KDE set this in its start up routine.
>
> Your path is a list of folders where Linux looks for commands (Tools, Utilities and Applications) to run.
>
> You can find out your path with the command line:
>
> ```
> $ echo $PATH
> ```
>
> The command to start the KDE GUI (Graphical User Interface) is a shell script called "startkde".
>
> The script checks to see that everything is cool for it to run correctly, and adds its command folder to your path.
>
> It does lots of other checks and sets up its graphics, fonts, and user preferences. Then it starts the X server and KDE.
>
> Running the command from the command line will let you see any error messages in case it does not start properly. What you do about these is beyond the scope of this answer as there could be many reasons why it didn't work. Hopefully the error messages will be self explanatory.
>
> You can run this command in two ways. Either by giving the full path name thus:
>
> ```
> $ /opt/kde3/bin/startkde
> ```
>
> or by:
>
> ```
> $ cd /opt/kde3/bin
>
> $ ./startkde
> ```

If none of those solutions work, I'd recommend running a repair or reinstall of KDE.

**Update 3:**

Try using xwmconfig to (re)set your X Window Manager to KDE

Comment: yes,opensuse 11.1 KDE

Comment: And what GUI were you using: Gnome, KDE, something else?

Comment: It is KDE music2myear

Comment: It tells me $DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the xserver

Comment: Then you're beyond my depth in Linux. It sounds like your graphics driver is messed up or the xserver (the window manager) is not running. Googling that error message gives some promising results from others who've had the same issue. It appears you'll need to try an alternative way of starting KDM.

Comment: $path showed me a path file without errors

Comment: I tried cd /opt/kde3/bin and then I started the kde it has error Error:can't open display: ./startkde:line80:/root/.kde/share/config.startupconfig:no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your computer:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: It just restarted me in again that mode

Comment: may be you can re-install the kde-desktop

zypper install -t pattern kde4 kde4_basis

http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:KDE_install

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the distribution, the X server may have taken over the slot usually occupied by tty1 or tty7. On Fedora, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> takes me back to the X server; <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> used to work on Ubuntu.

Failing that, X may have died - in which case you have two choices:

- Try `startx` - you'll need to be logged in and with the appropriate scripts configured; not all distributions have this.
- Restart init. To do this: log in, type:

  ```
  $ sudo -i
  # init 3
  # init 5
  ```

  You may need to re-login between the two inits, depending on your distribution. `init 5` means "start multi-user graphical mode" and should boot you up into X. `init 3` will likely kill any running applications you have, by the way.

Comment: startx tells me fatal server error read only file system /root/.serverauth.1505

Comment: You'll need to be root then; try `sudo -i` which should log you in to the interactive root prompt, then `startx`.

Comment: It tells me many errors xinit:no such process(errno 3):Server error errors in locking authorithy lobloblob

Comment: @nik hmmm. Have you tried the ctrl+alt+FX approach? Xs can be from 1-8 I think.

Comment: yes I tried them I wanna Die! Ireally need my desktop! I can't again install suse because I have many documents spread everywhere

Comment: This is why we have backups.